# Storing integers of a char pointer in c?

Tags: c, ansi-c

if player1 inputs: "A5-B2"   (ranges: A-G 1-7 )
so 
    char * input = "A5-B2"
and i want each data to be held like this:

```
int x1 = 1  (since A should be 1)
int y1 = 5
int x2 = 2 (if A=1, then B=2 and so on)
int y2 = 3
```

so I realize I can use strtok which separates a5 from b2 but how do i seperate a from 5 and b from 2?

Comment: what can the player input in general? any numbers > 9? multiple letters "AC4-D3"?

Comment: Letters: ABCDEFG  Numbers: 1234567

Comment: `strtok()` is often not a good choice, and in this example, is pretty much unnecessary.  A simple `sscanf()` would suffice, or you can check that the string is 5 characters long and simply convert the character at index 0 to a number (`str[0] - 'A' + 1`), the digit at index 1 to a number (`str[1] - '0' + 1`), and similarly at indexes 3 and 4.

Comment: How do you seperate ints from chars?  such as the case A5 should be int x = 1 and int y = 5 ?

Comment: Shouldn't `y2 == 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sscanf,

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

In this ,

```
 sscanf(input,"%c%d-%c%d",&ch1,&int1,&ch2,&int2);
```

After getting the input in separate variables, for the alphabets use like this.

```
int3=ch1-'A' + 1;
int4=ch2-'A' + 1;
```

Ascii value of `'A'` is 65. You need that as 1. So subtract by `'A'` and add one, store that in the variable it give that as 1 and so on. If that is lower case then subtract with `'a' +1`.

Comment: What is this `"A5-B2"`? in sscanf()?

Answer (score 0):

Since `char *` defines a character array, if you are limiting the user to ASCII then for `char * input = "A5-B2"`, you could directly access the individual character codes as elements of the array:

```
input[0] = 65
input[1] = 53
input[2] = 45
input[3] = 66
input[4] = 50
```

All digits fall withing 48-57, capital letters in 65-90 and lowercase letters in 97-122

simply branch based on the range in which the character code falls and store your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to convert each character to the integers you want because your input is of a fixed length and simple format with capital letters and single digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    char input[] = "A2-B3";

    x1 = input[0] - 'A' + 1; /* convert A -> 1, B -> 2 ... */
    y1 = input[1] - '0';     /* convert ASCII digit characters to integers '0' -> 0 ... */
    x2 = input[3] - 'A' + 1;
    y2 = input[4] - '0';

    if (x1 < 1 || y1 < 1 || x2 < 1 || y2 < 1
       || x1 > 7 || x2 > 7 || y1 > 7 || y2 > 7
       || input[2] != '-') {
       /* error: invalid input */
       printf("Invalid string\n");
    } else {
       printf("x1=%d y1=%d x2=%d y2=%d\n", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```